# Computing NDVI - Repeated calculation error message (Google Earth Engine)

Tags: ndvi

I am doing  simple calculation for NDVI using Landsat 7 TOA Reflectance (Orthorectified). Landsat seven has the following bands: B1-Blue, B2-Green, B3-red and B4-nir. I used the following code:

```
//Compute NDVI

var red = filtered.select('B3');

var nir = filtered.select('B4');

var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red));

Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min: 0, max: 1}, 'NDVI')


*"filtered" being my image that I am trying to calculate NDVI for.
```

When I run the code I get an error message in the Console that says "nir.subtract is not a function"....but it is. Has anyone experienced something similar, or is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var ndvi = filtered.normalizedDifference(['B4','B3']);
```

From documentation:

> ### `normalizedDifference(bandNames)`
>
> Computes the normalized difference between two bands. If the bands to
>   use are not specified, uses the first two bands. The normalized
>   difference is computed as (first − second) / (first + second).
>
> Arguments:
>
> - this:input (Image): The input image.
> - bandNames (List, default: null):
>
> A list of names specifying the bands to use. If not specified, the
>   first and second bands are used.
>
> #### Returns: Image